# socket.io is not working correctly with React js Node.js and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am trying to integrate the socket.io with React.js I am running socket.io on server with Express.js back end.

The problem is this I am on homepage and when order is placed from homepage then i am showing that order in the Orders page of React but the problem is it sometimes shows the order but it sometimes does not shows the order and if i open multiple tabs on different browsers then on some tabs in some browsers the order does not show mean the socket connection does not work some time but in all of the cases when ever a order is created from home page then the emit from the socket.io from home page is showing in the Node.js Express.js back end.

**Please note I am using clustering module on the express.js**

Here is how i am creating the socket.io connection.

```
socket = io('http://localhost:5000',{ reconnect: true ,transports: ['websocket']});
```

Here is my homepage react component from where i am placing the order.

```
socket.emit("putKitchenOrder", Order);
```

Here is my second component on which i want to show the order which is placed in real time using socket.io

```
componentWillUnmount(){
   socket.off("kitchen-channel:orderPlacedFromPos");
}
componentDidMount() {
    socket.on("kitchen-channel:orderPlacedFromPos",  (order) => {
        console.log('order in orderPlacedFromPos');
        console.log(order);
        alert('order in orderPlacedFromPos')

    });
}
```

Here is my Node.js and Express.js code

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("putKitchenOrder", order => {
    // this console.log is always showing in the node.js console window when ever a new order is placed from the homepage component but the second page is not getting the following emit "kitchen-channel:orderPlacedFromPos" sometime.
    console.log('putKitchenOrder order');
    io.emit("kitchen-channel:orderPlacedFromPos",order);

  });
});
```

The console.log('putKitchenOrder order'); is always showing in the node.js console window when ever a new order is placed from the homepage component but the second page is not getting the following emit "kitchen-channel:orderPlacedFromPos" sometime.

Comment: Have you any state that updates the component?,  eg.  If you put a `console.log` inside your `componentDidMount`, do you see more logs than you expect, because what might be happening is that while your `componentWillUnmount` is been called,  the server is doing the emit and at this point your client is going to miss it.

Comment: @Keith I have added a console.log statement in Second React page of orders in componentDidMount but it only shows me console.log one time when the page is load.and i am changing the state by adding the new order 
this.props.addNewPosOrderToKitchenDisplay(order)
using the above code but the above code does not run because the socket.io is not working.

Comment: I have tried adding console.log in componentWillUnmount to but it is showing me nothing on console because componentWillUnmount will only runs when i will leave the component.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know when you switch between components the components are mounted again. So maybe you can create a singleton for the socket instance like in this [article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34), and put a log in the file where you create the socket, you can debug with that and also can be the solution

Comment: I am creating a Single Instance of the socket.io inside the header following this article so their is always one instance of socket.io
I am following this article. 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-realtime-app-using-socket-io-react-node-mongodb-a10c4a1ab676/